# Elliptical path of planets

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics

Why are the planet's orbits in the form of an ellipse and what is the proof that earth moves in an elliptical path with the sun at its foci? Initially it was thought that earth moved in a circular orbit. Then,how was it discovered that it moves in an ellipse?

Comment: Very mathematical! http://radio.astro.gla.ac.uk/a1dynamics/ellproof.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't planets have Circular orbits?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69997/)

Comment: "Initially it was thought that earth moved in a circular orbit" is pretty much completely incorrect. At no point was this the case. You may be thinking of [Aristotle and Ptolemy's epicycle system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferent_and_epicycle). The only serious heliocentric proposal which involved circular motion was [that of Copernicus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernican_heliocentrism), which gave way to Kepler's observations of elliptical orbits within a century. In short, though, the proof is: we looked, and it isn't.