# Why is the Earth's or other planets orbit elliptical instead of being circular such as of moon?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets

Since bodies like planets moving around sun perform uniform circular motion where gravitation provides the necessary centripetal force,  so the orbits should be circular   for the gravitational force to be central but as we know the paths are not perfectly circular but elliptical. Why this is so?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69997/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The moons orbit is also elliptical with and eccentricity of 0.0549.

Comment: A circle is merely a special kind of ellipse.

Answer (score -1):

The paths do not always have to be elliptical. If there are any tidal forces at all, the orbit will tend to go circular.

Comment: Can you please explain your down vote.